# Complemented subspaces in projective limits

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X=\operatorname{proj}_nX_n$ be a projective limit of a sequence of complete DF-spaces and let $Y$ be its complemented subspace. Does it follow that $Y=\operatorname{proj}_nY_n$ where every $Y_n$ is complemented in $X_n$?

Comment: This is a very general question. I would guess that even for projective limits of Banach spaces this is a difficult question. Do you know the answer in that case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer for projective limits of Banach spaces but I have analyzed the proof that closed subspaces of PLS-spaces are again PLS. If I understand this proof correctly it shows in fact that - in our setting - I may write $Y=\operatorname{proj}_nY_n$ with each $Y_n$ - a closed subspace of $X_n$.

Comment: This is correct, the key ingredient is that closed subspaces of LS-spaces are LS. For DF-spaces this is no longer true.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Therefore we only know that $Y$ is a projective limit of a sequence of subspaces without claiming that they are DF. This would become true once we knew that $Y_n$ is complemented in $X_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I was hoping to conclude this from the fact that $Y$ is complemented in $X$.